# Image alignment using Homography with reduced opacity

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a program to align two images using homography. I am using cv2 in python. Here is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im_src = cv2.imread('src.jpg')
pts_src = np.array([[141, 131], [480, 159], [493, 630],[64, 601]])
im_dst = cv2.imread('dst.jpg')
pts_dst = np.array([[318, 256],[534, 372],[316, 670],[73, 473]])
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]))
cv2.imshow("Warped Image", im_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The above code works fine. Now I want to reduce the opacity of im_dst in im_out (say opacity=0.5), so that I can see both im_src and im_dst in im_out.
How to do that?

I checked a lot online and most use cv2.addWeighted, but I want reduced opacity of im_dst in cv2.warpPerspective, not just simple overlaying.

I am new to openCV, so I might be missing something simple. Thanks for help!

EDIT:

I tried the below to decrease the opacity of im_dst but all I am getting is a blackened wrapped image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
im_src = cv2.imread('src.jpg')
pts_src = np.array([[141, 131], [480, 159], [493, 630],[64, 601]])
im_dst = cv2.imread('dst.jpg')
pts_dst = np.array([[318, 256],[534, 372],[316, 670],[73, 473]])
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)
img1 = np.array(im_dst , dtype=np.float)
img2 = np.array(im_src , dtype=np.float)
img1 /= 255.0
# pre-multiplication
a_channel = np.ones(img1.shape, dtype=np.float)/2.0
im_dst = img1*a_channel
im_src = img2*(1-a_channel)
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]))
cv2.imshow("Warped Image", im_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: what's the difference between opacity reduction and transparent overlay?

Comment: @Micka When I use cv2.addWeighted I cannot match the coordinates of im_src and im_dst like in cv2.warpPerspective. How do I achieve both, matching coordinates as well as reducing opacity of im_dst

Comment: @Micka  I have edited the post. Now my query should be clear to you. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution! To get what I want we should add the faded and warped image to the destination image and output that. Also, its better to use `getPerspectiveTransform()` when we have four matching points, and `findHomography()` when we have more than four.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read source image.
im_src = cv2.imread('src.jpg')
# Four corners of the book in source image
pts_src = np.array([[141, 131], [480, 159], [493, 630],[64, 601]], dtype=np.float32)

# Read destination image.
im_dst = cv2.imread('dst.jpg')
# Four corners of the book in destination image.
pts_dst = np.array([[318, 256],[534, 372],[316, 670],[73, 473]], dtype=np.float32)

# Calculate Homography
h = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src, pts_dst)

# Warp source image to destination based on homography
warp_src = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]))

# Blend the warped image and the destination image
alpha = 0.5
beta = (1.0 - alpha)
dst_warp_blended = cv2.addWeighted(im_dst, alpha, warp_src, beta, 0.0)

# Show the output
cv2.imshow('Blended destination and warped image', dst_warp_blended)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```